# How to sync the state data saved in localstorage across all tabs using `Ngxs` state management?

Tags: angular, typescript, state-management, ngxs

I am saving all data of the state after converting it to `base64` format using `Ngxs state management` library. I can get all data across all tabs. But if I change a data in one tab it does not sync in the other tabs. To sync the data I have to refresh the tab. Is there any way to sync full state in all tabs if the state is changed in one tab?

Here is my code of `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ReadComponent,
    CreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxsModule.forRoot([
      TutorialState
    ]),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsLoggerPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
      storage: StorageOption.LocalStorage,
      serialize: (state) => btoa(JSON.stringify(state)),
      deserialize: (state) => JSON.parse(atob(state))
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by subscribing the storage event in the root component.

```
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    let source$ = fromEvent<StorageEvent>(window, 'storage');

    source$.subscribe(data => {
      this.store.reset(JSON.parse(atob(localStorage['@@STATE']));
    });

  }
```

Using this code all tabs synchronizes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few improvements over @abir 's answer so we don't reset if not necessary and also it seems that on my side the atob wasn't needed.

```
import { getDiff } from 'recursive-diff';
private storeCurrent: any = {};
async ngAfterContentInit() {
this.store.subscribe((store) => {
  this.storeCurrent = store;
});
let source$ = fromEvent<StorageEvent>(window, 'storage');
source$.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(async (data) => {
  const storeNew = JSON.parse(localStorage['@@STATE']);
  const diff = getDiff(this.storeCurrent, storeNew);
  if (diff.length) {
    console.log('reset store');
    this.store.reset(storeNew);
  }
});
```

}